# Angular CLI Config: Additional loaders

Tags: angular-cli

I want to add awesome-typescript-loader into my angular cli project without ng eject.

Is there a way to add additional loaders via .angular-cli.json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the developers, no.  See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1656.